# Exceptions while integrating : java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size

Tags: java, bouncycastle, ibm-jdk

I am integrating payment gateway integration and I do have bouncy castle jar deployed with an entry in java.security file `security.provider.11=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`

At run time, I do have the below mentioned exceptions; how can I resolve the issue?
java version is  `1.7.0 (IBM J9 VM)`

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You may try the unlimited strength key policy files https://www.oracle.com/it/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html get the one for your Java version.

Comment: Yes, IBMJava does have different policy files than Oracle/Open; it also has different _cryptoproviders_. The last time I managed to find useful files on (one of) the IBM website(s) was about 10 years ago, so I can't even suggest where to look :-(

Comment: @BigMike I have downloaded IBM version of files; it has worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. Please post the answer, will happy to accept and upvote.

Comment: @BigMike Below is the URL http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/security/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the unlimited strength key policy files
[here](http://ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/security/index.html)